# Equivalent to Rubys method_missing at global scales

Tags: python, ruby, metaprogramming, method-missing

I was doing a bit of metaprogramming lately and found it to be much easier in Ruby, mainly because the main context in Ruby is an object and I can override its method_missing.

Now, there are several constructs in Python that emulate that behaviour in CLASSES(e.g. with `__getattr__()`and then handle it apporpriately), but that does not apply on a global scale.

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to [this](https://github.com/mame/_/tree/master/lib) where the author makes "*_*" be a valid Ruby script by decoding it into a Ruby function. This of course is easy if you know that every time the interpreter does not know the method, he just falls back into a method you created.

You can emulate this in Python rather easily:

```
import _

try:
    ____ _ _____[and so on]
except NameError:
    [Handle it]
```

But this is somewhat clumsy and it would be much easier if you had to just include the module and not do anything else. That would be rather non-pythonic, I know that, but I am curious whether it would be possible without messing with the Python interpreter itself.

Does anyone know of a construct which allows for this behaviour?

Regards,
Carson

Comment: You're looking for import hooks, methinks.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, but im not quite sure how the source should be checked from inside the hook.